# Create bidirectional function in LTspice to use in behavioral source

Tags: ltspice, behavioral-source

I have a problem and that is that I'm trying to implement a custom function to a behavioral voltage source in order to model a varistor. The model that I'm using is based on the TDK varistor model and all I want to change is main function but I don't know how to make it continuous along the x axis. As the following Figure:

[image]

The latter figure is the TDK varistor model, which is done by the following subcircuit netlist:

```
    .SUBCKT SIOV 1 2 PARAMS: T=1 C=1pF L=1nH B1=1 B2=1 B3=0 B4=0
    R_SERIES  1 3 100u
    L_SERIES  3 4 {L}
    V_I_SENSE 4 5 0V
    H_I_SENSE 6 0 V_I_SENSE 10k
    R_I_SENSE 6 0 1G
    B_VAR     5 2 VALUE={T*(
    + PWR(10,
    + B1+B2*(LOG10(LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G))-4)+B3*EXP(-    
    LOG10(LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G))+4)+B4*EXP(LOG10(LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G))-4)
    + )
    + -PWR(10,
    + B1+B2*(LOG10(-LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-1m))-4)+B3*EXP(-LOG10(- 
    LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-1m))+4)+B4*EXP(LOG10(-LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-1m))-4)
    + )
    + +LIMIT((V(6)*1k*V(7)),-V(7),V(7))
    + )}
    C_PAR    4 2 {C}
    B_SW 7 0 VALUE={PWR(10,(B1+B2*(-7)+B3*EXP(+7)+B4*EXP(-7)))}
    R_SW 7 0 1G
    .ENDS
```

TDK is using the following equation to model the behavior of the varistor in the range of 10μA up to 10^5A:

[image]

And I want to subsitute the latter equation by this alternate version that I developed:

[image: formula]

So at this point I just need help to assemble a function that can produce a similar V-I curve as I showed in the previous figure where a bidirectional behavior is obtained.

One of the ideas that I've been tryint to implement is to create a smoth transition function and then implementing the full equations with "if" statements. But I dont really understand the TDK aproach on this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporal solution to the problem:

```
.SUBCKT MOV_model320 1 2 PARAMS: C=1pF L=1nH K1=640 K2=1.8 K3=-0.8 a1=0.03 a2=0.635 a3=-0.38 m=K1*    (10u)**a1 + K2*(10u)**a2 + K3*(10u)**a3
R_SERIES 1 3 100u
L_SERIES 3 4 20n
V_I_SENSE 4 5 0V
H_I_SENSE 6 0 V_I_SENSE 1
R_I_SENSE 6 0 1G
B_VAR 5 2 V={ 
+ (V(6)<-10u)*(-(K1*-LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-10u)**a1 + K2*- LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-10u)**a2 + K3*-LIMIT(V(6),-100G,-10u)**a3))+
+ (V(6)<=10u)*(V(6)>=-10u)*m*(1/10u)*v(6)+  
+ (V(6)>10u)*(K1*LIMIT(V(6),10u,100G)**a1 + K2*LIMIT(V(6),10u,100G)**a2 + K3*LIMIT(V(6),10u,100G)**a3) 
+}
.ENDS
```

Basically I'm assembling a linear function in between the positive and negative part of the curves.

The only thing is that has the same issue as the TDK varistor model an that is that a "Time step too small" error appears. I think that one of the reasons might be that the transition is not smooth making a disconiuous derivative. But Im not sure...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0P5xF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 and D2 produce a bipolar sigmoid-like voltage, as a function of current through them. Source I2 produces a current offset, to center the transition at 85μA on the X axis.

The diodes only develop half a volt or so, so I use VCVS1 to amplify it up to about ±200V. Then the slight voltage offset on the Y axis is introduced by V2.

Here's the relationship between current \$I_{IN}\$ and output \$V_{OUT}\$:

[image]

I'm sure you can write a spice .SUBCKT to implement this.

If you want to use an algebraic function, then start with the diode equation:

$$ I = I_S\left(e^{\frac{V}{\eta V_T}}-1\right) $$

Idealness factor for the 1N4148 I used here (the value used by CircuitLab, at least) is \$\eta=1.75\$, and saturation current \$I_S=2.52nA\$. The transition voltage used was \$V_T=25.4mV\$.

Rearrange to find V:

$$ V = \eta \cdot V_T \cdot ln\left(\frac{I}{I_S}+1\right) $$

Now introduce the offsets \$I_2=85\mu A\$ and \$V_2=+10V\$, and voltage scaling \$A=390\$:

$$ V_{OUT} = A \cdot \eta \cdot V_T \cdot ln\left(\frac{I_{IN}-I_2}{I_S}+1\right) + V_2 $$

That will be valid for \$I_{IN}>85\mu A\$, but you'll need also the inverted and mirrored version for \$I_{IN}<85\mu A\$:

$$ V_{OUT} = -A \cdot \eta \cdot V_T \cdot ln\left(\frac{-I_{IN}+I_2}{I_S}+1\right) + V_2 $$

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your answer. In my specific case I do need to apply the formula because I'm trying to model a varistor based on observed data by fitting a function to these data points . TDK uses that complicated logarihtmic exponential function and in my case I wanted to do it with the other version which is a sum of potential functions. The diode model is actually somewhat similar in shape but in my application I would need the equations that I mentioned to have more accurate results.